# How to Read Line From PDF file And Store In Database Table by java

Tags: java, database, backend

I Want to read line from pdf file & store every line in the Database table using java.

For Example I have Pdf file like This:[Pdf Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK0NH.jpg)

I want to add 1st line into first column (i.e Q) of database table, 2ndline into second column (A),3rd (B)and 4th(C) & 5th (D) Respectively. There are Number of Questions & their Options Present in the Pdf.

I Mean like This:[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LJ1Q.jpg)

Every Question Should Store in new Row of Table.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look to this one:

https://mkyong.com/java/itext-read-and-write-pdf-in-java/

You can use iText to read/write from/to a .pdf file.

https://itextpdf.com/en